# Opencart VERSION', '3.0.3.8: change image folder name

Tags: opencart

I've got OpenCart  VERSION', '3.0.3.8 and tried to change the image folder with unexpected results.

my config.php modified with following update

```php
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://example.com/opencart/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/opencart/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/newimagefolder/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/example/public_html/opencart/system/logs/');
```

After this modification I can't able to show my image from domain. its point to old image directory

```html
<img src="https://example.com/image/cache/catalog/DRESS/12-550x550.jpg" srcset="https://example.com/image/cache/catalog/DRESS/12-550x550.jpg 1x, https://example.com/image/cache/catalog/DRESS/12-1100x1100.jpg 2x" data-largeimg="https://example.com/image/cache/catalog/DRESS/12-1000x1000.jpg" alt="Dichus Shirt" title="Dichus Shirt" width="550" height="550">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your cache?

Have you moved your open cart installation into a sub folder?

Have you set this folder up in the htaccess

Your config.php doesn't seem to be opencart V3.0.3.8. You would typically have a storage define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE .